# Page attributes missing

Tags: templates, page-template, customization, page-attributes

*(I searched if anyone has same problem but found nothing. So if this is a duplicate question please let me know)*

My plan was to create a custome-page-template. So I found some tutorials and recognize that I have to create a `php-file` in template folder. All fine. Then I want to create a new page based on my template but there are no page attributes only empty dash bordered rectangl:

[image]

I remember my self that this empty rectangle was there for a while but I do not pay attention until now.

I'm relative new in using/administrating WordPress so I'm not sure where to start bug-hunting. Any help would be welcome.

WordPress-Version is 3.6 and theme is TwentyTen with some customizations in style.css (undo changes in css for test doesn't help)

Comment: Your template file should not effect the backend. Disable all of your plugins.

Comment: Is there a `Page Attributes` checkbox under the `Screen Options` tab in the upper-right corner?

Comment: @Milo: Thats it ... partly. Your comment helps. It was disabled but I have to activate the 1-colume-view. 2-colume-view still shows empty rectangle. If you will post your comment a answer I can accept it.

Comment: First of all, never add any changes or customizations to a theme directly.  The wordpress themes get updated regulary, so you will loose your changes.  Create a child theme and do all customizations in there. What debug information do you get when in debug mode. This might also help.

Comment: I was facing the same problem; the page attributes section just disappeared suddenly. However when I switched to the one-column view, it was right there. I can only surmise that the page attributes section disappeared from the 2-col template for some unknown reason, and since there are different template files for the 1-col and 2-col views. it can still be seen in the 1-col template.